# Can a Reverberation alter the fundamental frequency of reflected sound?

Tags: waves, frequency

I am aware that different surfaces can filter out or boost some harmonic frequencies of a reflected sound. But would it be possible that some surfaces could alter the fundamental frequency of reflected sound from the direct sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I suppose it might be possible to design an exotic device which absorbed energy from the incident sound wave at one frequency and re-emitted it at a different frequency (by analogy with light phosphors, etc) but that is not the conventional meaning of "reverberation" in acoustics.

Answer (score 1):

If the interaction with the wall is linear, the dynamics of the surface can only modify the existing harmonics of the incident sound wave--it can not create new ones.

Re. 'fundamental frequency'
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_frequency

> The fundamental frequency, often referred to simply as the
>   fundamental, is defined as the lowest frequency of a periodic
>   waveform. In music, the fundamental is the musical pitch of a note
>   that is perceived as the lowest partial present. In terms of a
>   superposition of sinusoids, the fundamental frequency is the lowest
>   frequency sinusoidal in the sum.

MY ANSWER:
*If we take the fundamental frequency to be the lowest frequency of a periodic waveform then it can not be altered by a linear interaction with the wall--except by setting its amplitude to zero.  That would cause the next higher harmonic to become the new fundamental.*

*If the interaction is non linear then it could be altered in other ways.*

Comment: Speaking in terms of acoustics, what do you mean by ‘non linear interaction’? Is it something like acoustic diffuser?

Comment: In terms of acoustics, it would mean something that created harmonics that did not exist before--typically higher harmonics.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.